# How to convert binary numbers into octal numbers?

Tags: javascript, numbers

I am making a JavaScript calculator,and it (suppose to) converts binary numbers (2) into octal numbers (8). I have done a research on this for a while, and what I found was a bunch of libraries. I don't want any of them and probably there is a simpler way to do this, but how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a library. Just use the [`parseInt` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and the [`toString` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString):

```
var binary = "10010100101";
var octal = parseInt(binary, 2).toString(8);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private double binToOct(int nm){
   String hex = "" + nm;
   long num = Long.parseLong(hex);
   long rem;
   while (num > 0) {
    rem = num % 10;
    num = num / 10;
    if (rem != 0 && rem != 1) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "This is not a binary number.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        return 0.0;
    }
   }
   long l = Long.parseLong(hex, 2);
   System.out.println(Long.toOctalString(l));
   return Double.parseDouble(Long.toOctalString(l));
   }
}
```

Write  Down This Code.